# O que está errado na implementação de multi-thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

A implementação abaixo é meramente uma classe de teste para testar concorrência em Java. São criadas várias Threads que executam um método que faz uma soma, posteriormente é exibido um retorno mostrando o resultado da soma. De acordo com os valores já implementados no código abaixo, o resultado correto é 100, porém ele fica oscilando entre 90 a 100 já que por algum erro de implementação, o processo paralelo impede de sempre retornar o valor correto, exibindo o resultado sem esperar todas as Threads terminarem de executar a soma.

O que fiz de errado?

INÍCIO DA CLASSE

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExercicioFinal {

    private final static List<Soma> listaSoma = new ArrayList<Soma>(0);
    private static final int LIMITE = 10;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < LIMITE; i++) {
            listaSoma.add(new Soma(10));
        }

        for (final Soma soma : listaSoma) {
            new Thread(soma).start();
        }

        exibirResultado(0);
    }

    private static void exibirResultado(final int i) throws InterruptedException {
        final Soma s = listaSoma.get(i);
        synchronized (s) {
            if (!s.foiExecutado()) {
                s.wait();
            }

            if ((i + 1) < listaSoma.size()) {
                exibirResultado(i + 1);
            } else {
                if (s.foiExecutado()) {
                    Soma.exibe();
                } else {
                    exibirResultado(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Soma implements Runnable {
    private static int resultado;
    private final int valor;
    private boolean executou = false;

    public Soma(final int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            resultado += valor;
            executou = true;
            this.notify();
        }
    }

    public boolean foiExecutado() {
        return executou;
    }

    public static void exibe() {
        System.out.println(resultado);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

O problema **não** era esperar as threads finalizarem. O código faz isto perfeitamente, embora de forma não otimizada, da seguinte forma:

1. Testa a primeira Thread e espera caso não tenha executado
2. Se não é a última thread, executa o passo 1 para a próxima thread (`i + 1)

## Melhorando a exibição do resultado

O código que implementa o algoritmo acima é este:

```
final Soma s = listaSoma.get(i);
synchronized (s) {
    if (!s.foiExecutado()) {
        s.wait();
    }

    if ((i + 1) < listaSoma.size()) {
        exibirResultado(i + 1);
    } else {
        if (s.foiExecutado()) {
            Soma.exibe();
        } else {
            exibirResultado(i);
        }
    }
}
```

O algoritmo poderia ser um laço, não precisava ser recursivo.

Além disso, o segundo `if` é redundante. É garantido que as threads vão terminar.

Portanto, o trecho poderia ser reescrito assim:

```
private static void exibirResultado() throws InterruptedException {
    for (final Soma s : listaSoma) {
        synchronized (s) {
            if (!s.foiExecutado()) {
                s.wait();
            }
        }
    }
    Soma.exibe();
}
```

## Corrigindo o problema

Bem, vamos ao problema então. Ele está em apenas uma linha de código:

```
resultado += valor;
```

Isso mesmo. O problema é que a operação acima **não é atômica**!

Esse conceito é importantíssimo: não é porque uma operação tem apenas uma linha ou um operador que ela necessariamente é atômica.

Aliás, mesmo operações que são atômicas como incrementos unitários (`var++`) podem gerar problemas quando threads executando em diferentes processadores usam um valor antigo da variável encontrada no cache local, que é defasado em relação ao cache dos demais processadores. Aqui entra o uso do `volatile`, mas não é o problema neste caso, então vou parar por aqui. :)

A solução neste caso é que a atualização da variável precisa ser sincronizada entre as threads. Uma forma simples de fazer isto é assim:

```
synchronized (Soma.class) {
    resultado += valor;
}
```

O bloco acima garante que apenas uma instância de `Soma` pode acessar a variável de cada vez, além do que ao final do bloco as outras threads vão ter o valor correto da variável.

Outra possibilidade é usar uma variável do tipo `AtomicInteger`. Exemplo:

```
private static AtomicInteger resultado = new AtomicInteger();
```

Depois incrementar assim:

```
resultado.addAndGet(valor);
```

Finalmente, imprimir assim:

```
System.out.println(resultado.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

O que faltou foi controlar se todas as Threads haviam finalizado, sua execução, eu apenas estava checando se a Thread havia sido executado, mas não se todas foram executadas. Utilizei o approach de contar o total de Threads executadas com uma variável estática int, de modo que se ela for igual ao tamanho da List (.size()) aí sim ele exibe o resultado da soma, caso contrário ele chama o método de novo no mesmo índice e fica em loop até que a Thread finalize sua execução. Done!

Segue código:

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ExercicioFinal {private static final int LIMITE_ITERACAO = 10;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final List<Somador> somaList = new ArrayList<Somador>(0);<br>
    for (int i = 0; i < LIMITE_ITERACAO; i++) {
    somaList.add(new Somador(10));
            }

            for (final Somador somador : somaList) {
                new Thread(somador).start();
            }

            exibirResultado(0, somaList);
        }

        private static void exibirResultado(final int index, final List<Somador> somaList) throws InterruptedException {
            final Somador somador = somaList.get(index);
            synchronized (somador) {
                if (!somador.executou()) {
                    somador.wait();
                }
                if (((index + 1) == somaList.size()) && (Somador.executados() == somaList.size())) {
                    Somador.exibir();
                } else if ((index + 1) < somaList.size()) {
                    exibirResultado(index + 1, somaList);
                } else {
                    exibirResultado(index, somaList);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Somador implements Runnable {<br>
    private static int contador;<br>
    private boolean executou;<br>
    private final int valor;<br>
    private static int executados;<br>

        public Somador(final int valor) {
            this.valor = valor;
        }

        public boolean executou() {
            return this.executou;
        }

        public static int executados() {
            return executados;
        }

        public static void exibir() {
            System.out.println(contador);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                contador += valor;
                executados++;
                this.executou = true;
                this.notify();
            }
        }

}
```